# Running Background Process using FFMPEG on Google Cloud Run stopping in middle

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have an external bash script that transcodes audio files using FFmpeg and then uploads the files to google cloud storage. I am using the google cloud run platform for this process but the process is stopping in the middle and not getting any clue from the logs. I am using the node js spawn command to execute the bash script

```
    const createHLSVOD = spawn('/bin/bash', [script, file.path, file.destination, contentId, EPPO_MUSIC_HSL_URL, 'Content', speed]);
    createHLSVOD.stdout.on('data', d => console.log(`stdout info: ${d}`));
    createHLSVOD.stderr.on('data', d => console.log(`stderr error: ${d}`));
    createHLSVOD.on('error', d => console.log(`error: ${d}`));
    createHLSVOD.on('close', code => console.log(`child process ended with code ${code}`));
```

on cloud run beginning the process itself taking a lot of time but in my local machine transcoding and uploading is very fast. after some time transcoding logs are being stopped and no new logs appear. I have no clue what is happening

[image: Google Cloud run logs]

so what is happening here? why it is very slow in the first place and why the process is being stopped in middle without any error

[node js script](http://gist.github.com/pashanitw/9b52e4835aad8d0e725ee971523ba3eb)

[Transcoding script](http://gist.github.com/pashanitw/94645c9cdbdcf0971325d3c642bc714b)

[Dockerfile](http://gist.github.com/pashanitw/313201e5e4d97da865a2aaadcb64f33b)

Comment: Can you share more parts of your code? For instance, how you handle the request and how do you package your code in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for responding this is my docker fille https://gist.github.com/pashanitw/313201e5e4d97da865a2aaadcb64f33b

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere first i am uploading the file to the temp directory inside the docker container then I transcode. uploading works fine but transcoding is not finishing. it is being stopped in middle. do you think cloud run container is becoming inactive because it is background spawning ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  here is my trascoding script https://gist.github.com/pashanitw/94645c9cdbdcf0971325d3c642bc714b

Comment: And the NodeJS code is only the 5 lines that you shared?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes mostly you can see the whole route here https://gist.github.com/pashanitw/9b52e4835aad8d0e725ee971523ba3eb

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `spawn` is that you create an asynchronous process that run in background. It's a problem, because Cloud Run allow CPU to the container only when a request is being processed. And in your case, you have that

- A request arrive
- A spawn is created

  - The spawned script run in background
- An HTTP answer is sent on the request. Cloud Run throttles the CPU

  - Your spawned script continue to run

There is 2 consequences

- Your script processing is very very long because the throttling limit the CPU under 5%
- After a period with activity (i.e. request received by the instance), Cloud Run kill the unused instance to same resource on its side. it's about 15 minutes, but it's subject to change, it's Google Cloud internal sauce

I recommend you to wait the end of the spawned script or to use a synchronous call; such as `execSync`, instead of async `spawn`.

Comment: I have tried execSync also but still, nothing is happening

Comment: @pashaplus Do you have some debugging statements on your scripts to at least diagnose where it stops working? "Nothing happens" is so un-specific that it can't be troubleshooted properly.

Comment: @pashaplus, did you ever resolve this?
i'm running into the same issue with cloud run and nodejs ... conversion is extremely slow. the same code on glitch is super fast though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for this issue is to change the approach of the architecture. Instead of using the client to upload the file to Cloud Storage through Cloud Run I would suggest using the signed URL. Signed URL provides permission and time to make a request, allowing users without credentials to perform specific action on a resource, for example you can give the user write access to a bucket for a limited time so they can upload a file. From the client side, this is very similar to your current process, changing the Cloud Run URL for the signed URL.

You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to read more about signed URLs, and here is a quick [guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers) of how to generate it.

For example, you can create a signed URL to test with this command:

First create a private key

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create "file where you want to storage the key" \
    --iam-account="name of the service account"@projectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Now you authenticate the service account

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file KEY_FILE_LOCATION/KEY_FILE_NAME
```

And now create the signed URL

```
gsutil signurl -m PUT -d 1h -c CONTENT_TYPE -u gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME
```

After that, the client uploads the file using the signed URL to the bucket in Cloud Storage. I would use Pub/Sub notification so you can know that the file was uploaded without any problem, and with that notification you can use it to trigger other operations in Cloud Run.

Basically Pub/Sub notifications are sent when an object changes in a specific bucket, you can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes#gsutil_1) that could help you configure that notification.

For example, to get notified about newly upload objects, you can configure it this way:

```
gsutil notification create -e OBJECT_FINALIZE -f json gs://<bucket name>
```

To use this notification to trigger a Cloud Run process you can see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push).