# fluent-ffmpeg processing is very slow in Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-run, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to merge multiple short videos in the container in Cloud Run using the node.js fluent-ffmpeg package. It takes 20 seconds max to merge videos locally. When I am making a request to clour run to merge the videos it processes them very slowly and after 30 minutes just stops (I assume that's because 1800 seconds timeout is set).
I tried to allocate to 2 CPUs with 8GB each but that didn't help. Within 30 minutes the video is processed by about 30 % as I can see in the cloud run logs.
Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Please check you have an active request ALL the time while the conversion runs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102462/running-background-process-using-ffmpeg-on-google-cloud-run-stopping-in-middle

Comment: Can you describe how do you run your job? What's the request lifecycle and the FFMPEG process?

Comment: Processing video is a compute-intensive task. I would not use Cloud Run for your objective. Either use a service designed for video processing or move your application to Compute Engine.